# Add same code to each webbrowser control

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Basically I already have a bunch of webbrowser controls drawn out, I want to add these few lines of code to each webbrowser control without having to do it for each one inside the webbrowser_navigating(sender, e) event of each webbrowser

```
While WebBrowser1.ReadyState <> WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
Application.DoEvents()
End While
```

my end goal is that I don't want the browsers causing the form to hang each time it can't load a page or when the webserver is taking forever to respond.

I'm thinking this has to do with an inheritable override?  but I have no experience with those but I'm starting to see the use for them if this is the case

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Inherit from WebBrowser Control and override the OnNavigating Method.

```
Public Class MyWebBrowser
    Inherits WebBrowser

    Protected Overrides Sub OnNavigating(e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs)
        MyBase.OnNavigating(e)
        While ReadyState <> WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
            Application.DoEvents()
        End While
    End Sub

End Class
```

Compile the project and a MyWebBrowser Control will appear in toolbox, use it instead of WebBrowser Control.
This is what you are willing to achieve but it is not a good practice to use Application.DoEvents() Method. There are many asynchronous methods available and you should use them.

Comment: RE: caution on doevents. This is a pretty good example of how you can get into trouble. You stall on a web site and the user tries to navigate to a new site. The first site may still be stuck in the While Loop - maybe not? Can't tell for sure. You could set a busy flag, and if set on reentry you may cancel the previous event, but how, you may not be on the same thread any more. Messy. Would take a lot of testing to figure out if it is working as expected and to hope you cover all the cases.

Comment: I've been trying forever to determine the best way to do asynchronous webbrowsing with the webbrowser control, but I have no clue where to start, I've found the Apt Threading and everything else, but it just doesn't seem to make sense, so if there's other ways, I'd love to hear/know how to do it!  Thanks @sarvesh!

Comment: Instead of overriding OnNavigating, override OnProgressChaged and remove the while loop. OnNavigating is called just once and while loop blocks main thread.